# pyodbc cannot find db id of existing database after another database has been dropped

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

Another user is using a database she has created in a python session, lets call it user_db. I, in SSMS, delete a different database, lets call it other_db. After I delete other_db, her scripts claim they are unable to find the db id for user_db. If she drops user_db and recreates it, the issue still exists. If she uses a new name like new_user_db her scripts work again.

To me it seems like something on the unixodbc/freetdbs/pyodbc/python side is caching database IDs. Can anyone enlighten me as to which tools might be causing the issue and possibly a solution for it?

error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Could not find database ID (id_number)

EDIT: 
Software Versions
pyodbc -- 4.0.16
centos  -- 6.6
unixODBC -- 2.2.14
freeTDS -- 0.91

Repeatable via:
User 1 (In Python):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(cxnstring)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE test')
cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE test_1')
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test_1.dbo.test_table (column_1 INT)')
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test_1.dbo.test_table')
```

User 2 (in SSMS):

```
DROP DATABASE test_1
```

User 1 (in Python):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(cxnstring)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE test_1')
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test_1.dbo.test_table (column_1 INT)')
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test_1.dbo.test_table')
```

Edit corrected SQL syntax

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue on Ubuntu 16.04 with unixODBC 2.3.1, FreeTDS 0.91, and pyodbc 4.0.17. Please [edit] your question with the versions you are using and a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Try your repro code again after replacing all occurrences of `test_1.test_table` with `test_1..test_table`. It looks like you are mixing up catalog (a.k.a. database) references with schema references in your [qualified object names](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: That would throw a syntax error which is not the error I'm receiving.

Comment: No, `database_name..object_name` is valid syntax.

Comment: FWIW, still unable to reproduce the issue using your updated code (with `test_1.dbo.test_table`) using unixODBC 2.3.1, FreeTDS 1.0.48, and pyodbc 4.0.17 on Xubuntu 16.04 x64.

Comment: Also, please clarify: In your initial description you talk about deleting "a different database", so should your repro steps actually have `DROP DATABASE test` instead of `DROP DATABASE test_1` ...?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I ran into was related to querying the Information_Schema after a database had been recently dropped by another connection. Running 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' every time one queries the Information_Schema of a db appears to resolve the issue.